# Canvas HTML5 Effects

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm looking for create a CANVAS effect on a logo, something like this:

http://www.teamgeek.co.za/

I couldn't find something like that. Someone know how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "I couldn't find something like that"? The page you linked to contains an example of how it can be done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like they used this plugin: http://particleslider.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review